# MongoDB $rename does not update target document even though source path exists

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make $rename work. In my test collection i have this document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5411466d90d39e816abe28e1"),
    "path" : "something",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

If i run `db.tests.update(ObjectId("5411466d90d39e816abe28e1"), {$rename: {'path': 'p'}})` nothing happens - document is not modified at all.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: Your syntax is quite wrong, try: `db.tests.update({_id: ObjectId("5411466d90d39e816abe28e1")}, {$rename: {'path': 'p'}})`

Comment: Doh! Thanks a lot - it works now. Weirdly this works ok `db.tests.find(ObjectId("5411466d90d39e816abe28e1"))`

Comment: Odd so it does, maybe a shortcut added in later versions of mongo shell so enable quick accession of documents via _id

Comment: Yeah, probably. Actually this could be Robomongo that introduces the shortcut. Very confusing.